# Expressing IN sql statement in Linq with computed string in where clause

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to build a linq query for the following sql query :

```
SELECT *
FROM [QryFiles2]
WHERE (left(Demande,6) IN (select NoBVR from tblRequest))
```

Knowing that QryFiles2 is an entity  and tblRequest too I've come to something like that :

```
from f in db.QryFiles2
where  f.Demande.Substring(0,6) /* in (select NoBVR from tblRequest) */
select f
```

The thing is I don't know how I could express the in sql statement using linq. Do you know how I could do that without using raw sql queries ?

Nb : I've tried to use the .contains method but I couldn't work it out with the computed substring.

Comment: Strange ! I've seen an answer to this post but it has disappeared ... what happened ??? Moreover it looks like it was working ...

Comment: The author of the answer (for whatever reason) decided to remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've done this using a join statement like that :

```
from f in db.QryFiles2
join r in db.tblRequest on f.Demande.Substring(0,6) equals r.NoBVR
```

Super clean super fast no need for subqueries should have thought about that before :-)